# How to transpose a google table chart without breaking the formatting

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am creating a table using Google charts / visualization API. The underlying data is shown in image 'table 1'. As you can see it has both numbers and dates. Google chart correctly shows it with proper data formatting and validation. I did have column level data types like 'date', 'number' etc.

However, my requirement is to transpose the table and show it as in image 'table 2'. If I try to do that then data validation and formatting fails as Google enforces that at column levels. If I mark the columns as string and then I may lose the validation and formatting.

How do I go about transposing the table without losing the data validation and formatting by Google charts API?

[table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoVhm.png)
[table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaQYU.png)

I tried to create the DataTable with the required rows and columns structure but I had to mark the data type as string. Otherwise, Google complains.

Comment: use a second data table for the transposition. then rename it as the first data table and discard it...